# "Server 's certificate does not match the url " when using self signed certificates

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have been trying to configure a website I deployed on my local server with a self signed certificate for development purposes. The address I want my website to work for is example.company.local.
After I genrated a certicate using SelfSSL, I copied it to the Local Machine store in both Personal and Trusted Certifciate root . But I get the error "Server's certificate does not match the url" when I try to reach the url. Though I can ignore it, I understand that the cert auth is failing and I want to fix this.  I am listing the steps I followed

1. Generated self signed cert using `selfssl /N:CN=example.company.local /V:9999`. This added the certiciate to my Personal store on Local Machine
2. From the mmc (type mmc in Run), I add the cert generated above to the to Trusted Root Certificate folder from the Personal folder
3. Restart IIS

Please suggest where I am going wrong. The url I give is `https://example.company.local`, but it refers to a localhost certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try [this guide](http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/). From the comments on the page it seems to be working but I did not test it.

If by any change there is still a problem I would suggest to use [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/). It is built on top of openssl, has very nice GUI and has templates for CA, SSL server and SSL client. Documentation can be found [here](http://xca.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks! Adding the certificate to the TrustedRootCertificateAuthroties->Local Computer was the part I was missing